# How to update this model that contains an array of objects in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I was wondering how I can update the array of likes with mongoose:

```
var postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    author: String,
    content: String,
    date: String,
    likes: [{theID: String}],
    numDate: Number
});

var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String
    },
    password: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String
    },
    first: {
        type: String
    },
    posts: [postSchema],
    last: {
        type: String
    },
    followers: [{theID: String}],
    following: [{theID: String}],
    img: { data: Buffer, contentType: String },
    admin: {type: Boolean, default: false}

});
```

I can push things like new posts to a certain user in the database by 
doing this:

```
User.update({_id: req.user.id}, {
    $push: {"posts": {_id : req.body.theData}}
}, function(err, user){
    res.redirect('profile');
});
```

Is there a similar way I can look at a specific user and then a specific post that the user has and update it to push a string to the likes array?

Answer (score 0):

First Of all you need to select the post where you want to update like dislike, you can do it with the help of _id of post `{_id: req.user.id,_id:posts._id}` then you will need to update like array that can be done this way `{$push: {"posts.$.likes": req.user.anotherUserId}} //anotherUserId is of user who liked it.` same way you can take a pull of user id if user dislikes the post to remove id from array.

```
User.update({_id: req.user.id,_id:posts._id}, {
        $push: {"posts.$.likes": req.user.id}
    }, function(err, user){

    });
```